# TypeError The Pearson correlation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
```

I try to find `Pearson correlation` to column `SibSp` and `Parch` and I use

`corr = data.corr(data['SibSp'], data['Parch'])`
but it returns `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `corr` method on a `DataFrame` does produce correlations for every combination, but the `corr` method on a `Series` requires another `Series` to correlate with.  So this would work as well:

#### Solution

```
data.SibSp.corr(data.Parch)
```